# JSON file not getting downloaded, function returns null

Tags: android, json

I am trying to download some JSON from the google book API.

The URL and API-Key I'm using seems to work becuase i can fetch it manually with a browser. I call this class and use this function passing it a usable URL. I've tried post and get(You can see where I've commited out the other.

While Im debugging I can watch it start the download process or it seems to but it always comes returns null.  It seems like it should be working.  any ideas of what might be happening?  A permission or something.(Already added **INTERNET PERMISSION**)

```
public static class JSONFunctions2 {
        public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

                /*//initialize*/
            InputStream is = null;
                String result = "";
            JSONObject jArray = null;

            //http post
            try{
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();

                     }catch(Exception e){
                  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                     }

                 //convert response to string
                 try{
                       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                   String line = null;
                   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
                   }
                   is.close();
                   result=sb.toString();
                   }catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                   }

                   /*DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                   HttpResponse getResponse;
                   getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
                   HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                   if (getResponseEntity != null) {
                     result= EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);
                    }*/

                    /*//try parse the string to a JSON object*/
                    try{
                            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    }

                    return jArray;
                }
    }
```

I guess this is the logcat (Im somewhat new to this, some of it on the top might because I switched my phone from wifi to reg. Phone Data)

```
11-06 23:02:23.716: ERROR/InputDispatcher(159): channel '4081c258 com.buddy/com.BuddyListActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-06 23:02:23.716: ERROR/InputDispatcher(159): channel '4081c258 com.buddy/com.BuddyListActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-06 23:03:36.616: ERROR/log_tag(4116): Error in http connection javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
11-06 23:03:36.616: ERROR/log_tag(4116): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 23:04:04.766: ERROR/log_tag(4116): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Any exception are you getting? check logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some informative input and research I've found a connection method that connects to the google book api and retrieves the JSON. The connection does use the TrustEveryOne class but it does retrieve the JSON. I'll have to work on certificate auth later, app isnt distributed yet.

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String urlpass) throws ParseException, IOException{

    /*//initialize*/
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlpass);
    TrustEveryone.trustEveryone();
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");        
    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            is = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
        }                     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    /*//try parse the string to a JSON object*/
    try{
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally does this way,might work for you as well

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);     
serverResponseJSON = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
Log.i("Server Response", serverResponseJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to get response from webservice and it works fine

```
try {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                        "webservice url");
                request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                // Build JSON string
                JSONStringer loginuser = new JSONStringer().object().key("userid")
                        .value(SetGetValues.getUserid()).endObject();
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(loginuser.toString());
                request.setEntity(entity);
                Log.v("data", loginuser.toString());
                // Send request to WCF service
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpClient1.execute(request);
                Log.v("response code", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
                        + "");
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                // Read response data into buffer
                char[] buffer = new char[(int) responseEntity.getContentLength()];
                InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
                reader.read(buffer);
                stream.close();
                results = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
    }catch(Exception e){
    // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**check out the following line**

```
Log.v("response code", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
                            + "");
```

if its value is 200 then you r getting ok response from server else you are not getting response from server

Comment: accept the answer if it helped you or tell if you still have problem in getting data

Comment: When I used this code instead of getting the no peer certificate error, I kept getting peer terminated connection error. I even tried to play with it a little because the google api authenticates differently.  I did however try this method with another webservice so it does work quite well, evidently just not with the google book api(that I could figure out).  I am posting my code that seems to be working with the google book api.  I am having to use the trusteveryone class(s) but at least Im able to continue with testing and development. I'll have to work with that before its distributed.