# return the json from restful webservice?

Tags: json, web-services

How to return the json object from restful web service( implementation jersey) method at server side where that json contains remote database table records.

Comment: what do you mean when saying return? generating it on server side or parsing on client?

Comment: where is android question? remove the tag if it doesn't belong there. there're plenty of tutorials about rest-ws http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html http://www.theserverlabs.com/blog/2009/01/12/rest-web-services-with-jaxb-jax-rs-and-sun-jersey/

Comment: see my answers here 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237422/how-to-call-net-webservice-from-android/8237544#8237544][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033305/json-file-not-getting-downloaded-function-returns-null/8033471#8033471][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237422/how-to-call-net-webservice-from-android/8237544#8237544
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033305/json-file-not-getting-downloaded-function-returns-null/8033471#8033471

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Anyway the answer depends on the server technology. For example Rails can easily output JSON data with almost no code